# Tomcat logback.xml - missing stacktrace after rolling file

Tags: java, tomcat, logback

I get from programers java *.war file, put it in /tomcat/webapps.
Start tomcat by /tomcat/bin/startup.sh.
In /tomcat/logs/ is file catalina.out - form here i read all logs from tomcat and java applications.
I have created file logback.xml in /tomcat/lib/ directory.

```
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
<property name="HOME_LOG" value="../logs/catalina.out"/>
       <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                        <fileNamePattern>../../logs/archived/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}_catalina.out.gz</fileNamePattern>
                        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <encoder>
                        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%.5level] %logger{10} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
        </appender>




        <root level="info">
                <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </root>
```

So I am testing application , i now there is a bug. I trigger an error in the application.
In catalina.out i get ERROR message and stacktrace of error - this is what i want.
After hour when file catalina.out is rolled,  I trigger the same error in the application again.
In catalina.out - i get just a short message ERROR, but no stack trace.
After restarting tomcat it works again until file is rolled.

I read that catalina.out is console output form tomcat server. So i add Console appender to logback.The result was that I had duplicate entries, after first file rolling, duplicates disappeared, stacktrace was showing. After second fille rolling no stacktrace.

```
<configuration scan="true" debug="true">
<property name="HOME_LOG" value="../logs/catalina.out"/>

<appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
                <target>System.err</target>             
                <encoder>
                        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%.5level] %logger{10} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
</appender>



       <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>
                <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                        <fileNamePattern>../../logs/archived/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}_catalina.out.gz</fileNamePattern>
                        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <encoder>
                        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%.5level] %logger{10} - %msg%n</pattern>
                </encoder>
        </appender>




        <root level="info">
                <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
                <appender-ref ref="STDERR"/>
        </root>
```

When I change `<property name="HOME_LOG" value="../logs/catalina.out"/>` to `<property name="HOME_LOG" value="../logs/mycatalina.log"/>` then, all stacktrace are written to catalina.out and application logs to mycatalina.log, but is hard to match log entries.

I used logrotate for a while, but now I have 30 instances of tomcat (each instance is one client), on one server. There will be more
One tomcat , one catalina.out = one crontab entry, is hard to maintain.

I would like to have logs in one file the console output from tomcat, application logs and backups them.
Is it possible to do that using logback.xml or maybe it is possible to rotate catalina.out using loggin.properties ?

Comment: Take a look at journalctl or /var/log/messages, stderr might be there.

Comment: No, nothing there. My goal is to have all logs is to write to catalina.out. As i As I wrote above, all logs appear in catalina.out until the file is rolled.

Comment: Giving it a second thought, your application log rotation might be colliding with tomcat own log rotation. Check if `/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat` or similar exists. A solution could be to remove log rotation from your config and rely on tomcat's one.

Comment: No, nothing there too. I have not install tomcat as a service, just downloaded gz archive unpack and run startup.sh in /tomcat/bin/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Logback deleted the catalina.out file and created a new one. Tomcat kept redirecting logs to the "old" catalina.out file which no longer existed.
I asked the developers to make stacktrace supported by the java application. Now after log rotation, errors from stacktrace are still written to catalina.out